# Problem with Indexed View in SQL Server, Error 8646

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I was just prototyping a new system for deferring certain operations until out of hours on one of our databases. I've come up with (what I think) a pretty simple schema. I was first prototyping on SQL Server 2005 Express, but have confirmed the same problem on 2008 Developer. The error I'm getting is:

> Msg 8646, Level 21, State 1, Procedure
>   Cancel, Line 6 Unable to find index
>   entry in index ID 1, of table
>   277576027, in database 'xxxxxx'. The
>   indicated index is corrupt or there is
>   a problem with the current update
>   plan. Run DBCC CHECKDB or DBCC
>   CHECKTABLE. If the problem persists,
>   contact product support.

The schema I'm using is:

```
create schema Writeback authorization dbo
    create table Deferrals (
        ClientID uniqueidentifier not null,
        RequestedAt datetime not null,
        CompletedAt datetime null,
        CancelledAt datetime null,
        ResolvedAt as ISNULL(CompletedAt,CancelledAt) persisted,
        constraint PK_Writeback_Deferrals PRIMARY KEY (ClientID,RequestedAt) on [PRIMARY],
        constraint CK_Writeback_Deferrals_NoTimeTravel CHECK ((RequestedAt <= CompletedAt) AND (RequestedAt <= CancelledAt)),
        constraint CK_Writeback_Deferrals_NoSchrodinger CHECK ((CompletedAt is null) or (CancelledAt is null))
        /* TODO:FOREIGN KEY */
    )
    create view Pending with schemabinding as
    select
        ClientID
    from
        Writeback.Deferrals
    where
        ResolvedAt is null
go
alter table Writeback.Deferrals add constraint
    DF_Writeback_Deferrals_RequestedAt DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP for RequestedAt
go
create unique clustered index PK_Writeback_Pending on Writeback.Pending (ClientID)
go
create procedure Writeback.Defer
    @ClientID uniqueidentifier
as
    set nocount on

    insert into Writeback.Deferrals (ClientID)
    select @ClientID
    where not exists(select * from Writeback.Pending where ClientID = @ClientID)
go
create procedure Writeback.Cancel
    @ClientID uniqueidentifier
as
    set nocount on

    update
        Writeback.Deferrals
    set
        CancelledAt = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    where
        ClientID = @ClientID and
        CompletedAt is null and
        CancelledAt is null
go
create procedure Writeback.Complete
    @ClientID uniqueidentifier
as
    set nocount on

    update
        Writeback.Deferrals
    set
        CompletedAt = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    where
        ClientID = @ClientID and
        CompletedAt is null and
        CancelledAt is null
go
```

And the code that provokes the error is as follows:

```
declare @ClientA uniqueidentifier
declare @ClientB uniqueidentifier
select @ClientA = newid(),@ClientB = newid()

select * from Writeback.Pending
exec Writeback.Defer @ClientA
select * from Writeback.Pending
exec Writeback.Defer @ClientB
select * from Writeback.Pending
exec Writeback.Cancel @ClientB  --<-- Error being raised here
select * from Writeback.Pending
exec Writeback.Complete @ClientA
select * from Writeback.Pending
select * from Writeback.Deferrals
```

I've seen a few others encountering such problems, but they seem to either have aggregates in their views (and a message back from MS saying they'd remove the ability to create such indexed views in 2005 SP 1), or they resolved it by applying a merge join in their join clause (but I don't have one).

Initially there was no computed column in the Deferrals table, and the where clause in the view was testing the CompletedAt and CancelledAt columns for NULL separately. But I changed to the above just to see if I could provoke different behaviour.

All of my SET options look right for using indexed views, and if they weren't, I'd expect a less violent error to be thrown.

Any ideas?

Comment: As I indicated in my comment to Mladen Prajdic - I can run the above scripts in a freshly created database, and still get this error. If an index could become corrupted that fast (create on empty table, 2 inserts), then I'd be seriously worried about SQL Server's stability. Also, as indicated, I've found "other" causes online which bring up this message, and they're not actually index corruption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work out what's causing this error, by trying to build up this script, from scratch, adding in pieces as I went.

It's some kind of bug that's produced if the view is created as part of a CREATE SCHEMA statement. If I separate the CREATE SCHEMA into it's own batch, and then create the table and view in separate batches, everything works fine.

---

Long overdue edit - I raised this on Connect [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/472439/indexed-view-create-via-create-schema-statement-can-produce-error-8646-during-updates). It was confirmed as being an issue in SQL Server 2008.

Internal builds (in 2010) indicated it was no longer an issue, and I have (just now, 2016) confirmed that the script in the question does not generate the same error in SQL Server 2012. The fix was not back-ported to SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

you have index corruption. run checkdb and see what errors it gives you. the easiest thing you could do is to rebuild your indexes.

also take a look at this [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/822747) if it applies to your sitution.

Also note that putting a primary key on a GUID column will create a clustered index on it which is the worst thing performance wise you could do.

Comment: Index corruption - in a database/schema/index that I created 10 minutes ago, specifically for this prototyping? (Also, repeatable in fresh database)

Also, yes, aware of all kinds of issues with using GUIDs. But that's what I'm stuck with in this database. The actual guids for clients are actually generated with newsequentialid(). Not worried about performance at the moment.

Comment: I've aldo just modified the above scripts to use int in place of uniqueidentifier, and get the same error, so it's not related to this problem